# Oracle XE 11g (ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor )

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer, oracle-xe

I have already seen the questioned in the stack overflow that might relate to my problem but let me emphasize that none of them could resolve my issue.

issue is: when I wanted to integrate OWASP WebGoat application with oracle XE 11g , I receive the above mentioned error.

connection URL in web.xml is:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE/${USER}
================================================================= listener.ora:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER = 
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Amir-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
============================================================= tnsnames.ora:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Amir-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 
=================================================================== java version:

java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
=================================================================== output of the lsnrctl services:

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 09-MAY-2014 16:34
:07

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER 
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Amir-PC)(PORT=2403))
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
===================================================================== output of the tnsping xe :

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 09-MAY-2
014 16:35:19

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Amir-PC)
(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (0 msec)
could some one please help me resolve this issue? I have been struggling more than 3 days and not found any useful answer yet.

Comment: The username doesn't go at the end. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832056/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-service-name-instead-of-sid

Comment: @Phil could you please give a solution?

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521  <=== this will give invalid connection string format error. suppose system/system is user/pass

Comment: invalid username password logon error while I am sure system/system is the one I can login to GUI interfce of oracle XE

Comment: by the way i have created another database user is SQL CLI mode with amir/amir like this:   SQL> create user amir identified by amir default tablespace system quota 5m on system;   <=== still invalid user/pass logon error.